# Laws of Logic Negation Simple

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I cant quite remember, when you are using the laws of logic to simplify an argument or an argument about sets. Do you start on the outside of the brackets with the outer most negation? Or the inner most?

This example is for set theory. 
ex. $\bigg(\Big(\big((A \cup B) \cap C\big)^c\Big) \cup B^c\bigg)^c$

I am not sure how to use LaTex, but by the "^c" I mean the complement of the set or intersection of sets in the brackets
A, B, C are subsets of some universe U

Comment: Your set expression isn't very clear. Also, can you please edit your post to use LaTeX to make it more readable for us?

Comment: MathJaxed it for you.  Place dollar signs around the math text.  Use `\cap` and `\cup` for $\cap$ and $\cup$.  The caret `^` will raise the `c` to superscript.  Still needs work though.  Is that last complemented B supposed to be unioned or intersectioned?

Comment: Sadly, @Graham's rendering in LaTeX hasn't rendered your expression more sensible. I suspect that it is supposed to be either $$\bigg(\Big(\big((A \cup B) \cap C\big)^c\Big)\cap B^c\bigg)^c,$$ rendered `\bigg(\Big(\big((A \cup B) \cap C\big)^c\Big)\cap B^c\bigg)^c`, or $$\bigg(\Big(\big((A \cup B) \cap C\big)^c\Big)\cup B^c\bigg)^c,$$ rendered `\bigg(\Big(\big((A \cup B) \cap C\big)^c\Big)\cup B^c\bigg)^c`.

Comment: thank you for your help with that!

Comment: either way, do i work from the outside in? or the inside out when I go to simplify the expression?

Comment: You can do either way.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. I will keep working on my problems.

Comment: Although theoretically i doesn't matter, it is often more efficient to work from the outside in.

Comment: I was simplified the second expression in Cameron's comment to (B /cap C). Is that correct? (I still dont get the notation, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

$$\Big(\big((A \cup B) \cap C\big)^c \cup B^c\Big)^c$$

You can either start negating from the outside in or from the inside out.  Doing the former may save redundancy.

$$
\Big(\big((A \cup B) \cap C\big)^c \cup B^c\Big)^c
\\ = \Big(\big((A \cup B) \cap C\big) \cap B\Big)
$$

Versus 
$$
\Big(\big((A \cup B) \cap C\big)^c \cup B^c\Big)^c
\\ = \Big(\big((A \cup B)^c \cup C^c\big) \cup B^c\Big)^c
\\ = \Big(\big((A \cup B)^c \cup C^c\big)^c \cap B\Big)
\\ = \Big(\big((A \cup B) \cap C\big) \cap B\Big)
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can start however you like. To use your example:

$$((((A\cup B)\cap C)^c)^c\cup B^c)^c$$
$$((A\cup B)\cap C)^c\cap B$$
$$((A\cup B)^c\cup C^c)\cap B$$
$$((A^c\cap B^c)\cup C^c)\cap B$$
or
$$((((A\cup B)\cap C)^c)^c\cup B^c)^c$$
$$(((A\cup B)^c\cup C^c)^c\cup B^c)^c$$
$$(((A^c\cap B^c)\cup C^c)^c\cup B^c)^c$$
$$((((A^c\cap B^c)^c\cap C)\cup B^c)^c$$
$$(((A\cup B)\cap C)\cup B^c)^c$$
$$((A\cup B)^c\cup C^c)\cap B$$
$$((A^c\cap B^c)\cup C^c)\cap B$$

Obviously, one way is easier, but both are valid.